# Crear Grupos Automaticamente en laravel a my sql

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo un problema a la hora de crear grupos el sentido es que necesito crear grupos y enlazarle a cada usuario n cantidad de archivos tengo se debe de crear grupos 
[image: imagen ilustrativa de las tablas que tiene que escoger.]

la imagen me muestra dos tablas, una  con n cantidad de usuarios pueden ser más. y la otra son los archivos que se deben escoger a esos clientes para final ocupo que me cree grupos de 4 osea los primeros 4 y luego los otro 4 con los mismos archivos.  por ejemplo grupo uno tiene us01,us02,us05,us06 y el grupo 2 tiene us03 us04 us07 por ejemeplo y esos tienen que tener los archivos cada cliente el archivo  us03 con los archivos 1,  2,  3 y asi sucesivamente.

```
 public function automaticGroup(Request $request){

    $cliente = $request->input('clientes');
    $variable = array_chunk($cliente, 4, true );
    foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
        # code...

    $data = $request->only('clientes','email','archivos','asunto');

    $test['data'] = json_encode($data);

    Boletin::insert($test);
    }
    return  Redirect::to('/Admin/clientgroup/createClientGroup')->withSuccess('Great! Successfully store data in json format in datbase');
}
```

tengo este codigo.  pero no me genera lo que busco, intente hacer la divido array_chunk()  que me separa los array's pero no ecuentro como.

Comment: Yo por lo menos no entiendo casi nada, solo que deben haber unas relaciones, algo así. ¿Las relaciones se hacen de forma automática o manual? Asumiendo (según el título) que son automáticas, ¿cómo se determina qué usuarios y qué archivos están relacionados?

Comment: el usuario selecciona los archivos que son necesarios y se seleccionan todos los clientes después de eso al darle generar el deberá separar todos los clientes en grupo de 4 por clientes,  con los archivos que se seleccionaron. ya el hace el recorrido pero al json que le agrego se me repiten los clientes.

Comment: ¿los usuarios son distintos a los clientes?

Comment: si un usuario es un administrador y los clientes, son los que estan en la lista de la izq en la imagen

Comment: Falta una mejor explicación a lo que quieres, y esa imagen que tienes tachado, no se nota mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que la explicación no es tan clara (para mí), planteo una respuesta simple, a la espera de obtener mejor información que indique exactamente lo que se desea.

---

Según entiendo, la idea es asignarle los archivos a cada cliente, y además dividir los clientes en grupos de 4, para lo cual planteo este código que genera al final una estructura `key => value`, en donde la llave es el nombre del usuario, y el valor es el arreglo de archivos seleccionados:

```
$files = $request->archivos;
// ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3']

$clients = $request->clientes;
// ['us01', 'us02', 'us03', 'us04', 'us05', 'us06']

$clientsGroups = [];

foreach ($clients as $client) {
    $clientsGroups[$client] = $files;
}

$clientsBlocks = array_chunk($clientsGroups, 4, true);
```

El contenido de `$clientBlocks` sería un arreglo multidimensional:

```
[
    'us01' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us02' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us03' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us04' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
],
[
    'us05' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us06' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
]
```

Comment: esta bien, es lo que quiero hacer, pero una pregunta para guardar eso en base de datos, sirve algo como `$client = new Boletin();` y guardo el `$client->data = $clientsBlocks; $client->save();`

Comment: ¿guardar un array de ese tipo en la base de datos?

Comment: si es que ocupo que me lo guarde en base de datos para luego poder seleccionarlos arrays como grupos.  osea digamos que el [
    'us01' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us02' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us03' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
    'us04' => ['archivo1', 'archivo2', 'archivo3'],
], ese es un grupos y ocupo seleccionar a todos los usuarios de esa parte del array.

Comment: Lo que yo haría, sería almacenarlos como json en la base de datos, me parece más fácil de manejar, y se puede convertir fácilmente desde y hacia un array. También podrías usar `serialize()` para almacenarlos como un string. Revisa la documentación de PHP.

Comment: Ok, gracias creo que me encaminaste,